# Question about a corollary to the theorem on the dimension of fibres.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The highlighted sections are taken  from Volume 1 of "Basic Algebraic Geometry" by Igor Shafarevich.

> **Theorem**: Let $ f : X \rightarrow Y $ be a regular map between irreducible varieties. Suppose that $ f $ is surjective, and that $ \text{dim}(X) = n, \text{dim}(Y) = m. $ Then $ m \leq n, $ and
>
> - $ \text{dim}(F) \geq n-m $ for any $ y \in Y $ and for any component $ F $ of the fibre $ f^{-1}(y). $
> - there exists a nonempty open subset $ U \subset Y $ such that $ \text{dim}f^{-1}(y) = n-m $ for $ y \in U. $
>
> **Corollary:**
>   The sets $ Y_{k} = \lbrace y \in Y \; | \text{dim}f^{-1}(y) \geq k \rbrace $ are closed in $ Y. $

The proof of the corollary is as follows(paraphrasing):

> We know that $ Y_{n-m} = Y, $ and there is some closed subset $ Y' \subsetneqq Y $ such that $ Y_{k} \subset Y' $ if $ k > n-m. $

It is clear that $ Y_{n-m} = Y. $ I'm not entirely sure why there must exist such a closed set $ Y' $ however.

The proof continues:

> If $ Z_{i} $ are the irreducible components of $ Y' $ and $ f_{i}: f^{-1}(Z_{i}) \rightarrow Z_{i} $ the restrictions of $ f $ to $ Z_{i}. $ 
>   Then $ \text{dim}(Z_{i}) < \text{dim}(Y), $ and we prove the corollary by induction on $ \text{dim}Y. $

I don't see why $ \text{dim}(Z_{i}) < \text{dim}(Y). $ Why is it not possible for $ \text{dim}(Z_{i}) = \text{dim}(Y)? $ I'm also unclear on how the induction is done.

Comment: The closed subset $Y'$ is the complement of $U$ defined in the second bullet point of the theorem. You may use the definition of dimension as longest chain of proper inclusions of irreducible closed subsets to see the claim about dimension (take a chain showing $Z_i$ is of dimension $n$, then append $Y$ to the end, now it's longer, so $\dim Y > \dim Z_i$). Have you tried any examples of the induction to see how it should work?

Comment: @KReiser I see why $ \text{dim}(Z_{i}) < \text{dim}(Y). $ I had not tried any examples because I couldn't think of any examples, which is silly because I just need an irreducible variety, find some closed subset of it and a chain of irreducible components of that.

Comment: I think that the corollary as stated may be incorrect; see David Speyer's [answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/184925/33088).